# Marklogic : "highlight" seem not work withe Node.js and QueryBuilder

Tags: node.js, highlight, marklogic

I try to get an extract of the text with the searched words highlighted on a JSON collection.
My search syntax is:

`qb.word(qb.field('doc_text'),vartxt)`

With `'doc_text'` declared as field 
`(field type: root, include root: false, includes: doc_text)`, in an Node.js application.

The search works well, and it is done well on this field ...
But in `txt[0].results[kl].matches[0]['match-text']`, I find the first 3 properties of the JSON,
and not an extract from `'doc_text'` with the words found.
I have another application in which the highlights work correctly, but it is based on XML.

Did I forget something in the field declaration, or is the operation different between JSON
and XML data, or is the highlight system not running on JSON via Node.js and QueryBuilder ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Fields do not work quite the same way in XML and JSON. I think you're running into this limitation:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json#id_24090

The value of a field in XML can be the concatenation of all the text nodes, but the same does not apply in JSON.

Comment: I had already read this page. I do not think this limitation is the cause of the problem. The field is a simple field, the global content of a "pdftotext", without subfield or concatenation. And the search works correctly....

Comment: Is the query on the XML also a field query?  Snippeting (which is what generates the matched text for both JSON and XML) uses the server cts.walk() function, which might not match fields.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same query, based on node.js and querybuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood !!!

This query gives a correct snippet, with the extract and the words highlighted :
mkcq.and(mkcq.collection('document'), mkcq.word(mkcq.field('doc_text'), 'connaitre'))

On the other hand, this query gives the first 3 fields of the JSON :
mkcq.and(mkcq.collection('document'), mkcq.word(mkcq.field('doc_text'), 'connaitre'), mkcq.value(mkcq.element('','doc_user'), 'mbp'))

I do not know if this is normal or not, but it should be able to be corrected either by a simplified query and a selection on the returned records, evening by a particular snippeter.

Kind regards